# Revoke permission to add contacts to groups

Tags: contacts, groups, permissions, admin, administer

My client has a strange and complex group of relationships that I'm trying to properly permission. We are granting permission to a group of 3rd party managers to admin protected groups of contacts. All of that is working correctly.

However, I see that these 3rd party managers have the ability to add users existing groups. They do not have permission to do anything else with groups. I want to find a way to lock them out of the this ability. I don't want anyone being accidentally added to a mailing or permissions group, for example.

I do want these managers to have permission to edit their client's profiles. We want leverage the manager's ability to provide us with correct contact information on profiles, and to do event registrations.